# HTML form submits an empty string when JavaScript indicates the hidden control has a value

Tags: html, forms, submit

Amongst many other controls, I have the following HTML elements on a form

```
<input ID='cmdRegisterMe' name='cmdRegisterMe' value='Register Me' onclick="return preSubmit();"  type='submit'  />
<input type="hidden" ID="NewHash" name="NewHash" value="">
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" ID="email" NAME="email" VALUE="" SIZE="50" MAXLENGTH="50">
<INPUT TYPE="PASSWORD" ID="password1" NAME="password1" VALUE="" SIZE="30" MAXLENGTH="25">
<INPUT TYPE="PASSWORD" ID="password2" NAME="password2" VALUE="" SIZE="30" MAXLENGTH="25">
```

and JS functions

```
function preSubmit() {

  document.getElementById("NewHash").value = doNewHash(document.getElementById("password1").value, document.getElementById("email").value.toLowerCase());
alert(document.getElementById("NewHash").value);
  document.getElementById("password1").value = '';
  document.getElementById("password2").value = '';
  return true;
}

function doNewHash(pw, strUsername) {
  var hash_padding = '************';
  return SHA1(SHA1(pw) + hash_padding + strUsername);
}
```

When I click Submit, I see the expected hashed value displayed by the call of alert().

However, in my PHP, the value of $_POST['NewHash'] is an empty string. I cannot fathom why this happens. In my understanding, there is no other code executed after the onclick() function returns true. I have done a global search on my code for 'NewHash' and there are no other assignments to it.

If I replace this line

```
  document.getElementById("password1").value = '';
```

with this

```
  document.getElementById("password1").value = document.getElementById("NewHash").value;
```

and inspect $_POST['password1'], it contains the hash value. What on earth could be happening to wipe out the value of 'NewHash'?

Answer (score 0):

I have found what was wrong, but I hope posting the question may help someone else. I saved the PHP-generated HTML as a file, added  to the top, and resolved to remove code piece by piece and submit until the submitted value for NewHash was no longer empty. I found I had TWO hidden controls called NewHash - so JS was displaying the value in one, and the browser was submitting the other!